# Run javascript function after Postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

How do i run a javascript event after a postback within an updatepanel

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the ClientScriptManager to make a call to a function on the reload:

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AKey", "MyFunction();", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Comment: @Profeten - is that not what you asked for though?

Comment: I do it like this

$("#divGetListforUser .btn").click(function() {
      isClicked = true;
     });
and set it false after the postback

Comment: i used `ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement()`  to reload captcha within a `!IsPostBack` if block and it works like a charm, solved my issue because captcha was a user control etc

Answer (score 81):

You can use `endRequest` event of `PageRequestManager`.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>   
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function (s, e) {
        alert('Postback!');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried the above method but get a Script Error saying Sys is undefined.... any ideas?

Comment: @Mych The "Sys is undefined" error occurs when you place the prm before the "asp:ScriptManager". In order for this to work, the javascript code for the prm variable declaration and the add_endRequest must be after the script manager. Furthermore, VB.net users may want to remind themselves that the "Sys.WebForms..." is case-sensitive unlike the code-behind it resembles.

Comment: This works great but blocking further postbacks. any solution?

Answer (score 13):

Simply

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function pageLoad() { 

  } 
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"> 
  <ContentTemplate> 
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" /> 
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="TextBox1" /> 
 </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**pageLoad() will then continue to be called each time Button1 is triggered**

[Read this by Dave Ward](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function(){
// Handle the beforeSend event
},
complete: function(){
// Handle the complete event
}
// ......
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me alot. It's clean and no Backend stuff is needed.

Comment: best! you could add a _dopostback in the before and exec something after, fanstastic!

Answer (score 1):

For use within an UpdatePanel i would use the [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx)