# How to call javascript function on page load in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

i have application in asp.net 4.0

i have javascript to display client zone offset into text box:-
`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetTimeZoneOffset() {
        var d = new Date()
        var gmtOffSet = -d.getTimezoneOffset();
        var gmtHours = Math.floor(gmtOffSet / 60);
        var GMTMin = Math.abs(gmtOffSet % 60);
        var dot = ".";
        var retVal = "" + gmtHours + dot + GMTMin;
        document.getElementById('<%= offSet.ClientID%>').value = retVal;
    }

</script>
```

`

**Html MarkUp**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="clientDateTime" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="offSet" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></body>
```

How can I call this function on page load so that I can display offset into textbox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Comment: Actually, I don't think this a duplicate.  The referenced question is about general HTML / JavaScript interaction.  This question and the relevant answer is specific to ASP.NET.  I came here because of the ASP.NET issue.

Answer (score 30):

Calling JavaScript function on code behind i.e.
On `Page_Load`

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:FUNCTIONNAME(); ", true);
```

If you have `UpdatePanel` there then try like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:FUNCTIONNAME(); ", true);
```

Comment: I tried this but page can not identify ClientScript it give error for that

Comment: @MonaliJ: paste here what you tried ?

Comment: Perhaps this changed in recent versions of .NET but with framework 4, call something like this:  ClientScriptManager scriptManager = Page.ClientScript; scriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript",  "javascript:functionName(); ", true);

Answer (score 9):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetTimeZoneOffset() {
    var d = new Date()
    var gmtOffSet = -d.getTimezoneOffset();
    var gmtHours = Math.floor(gmtOffSet / 60);
    var GMTMin = Math.abs(gmtOffSet % 60);
    var dot = ".";
    var retVal = "" + gmtHours + dot + GMTMin;
    document.getElementById('<%= offSet.ClientID%>').value = retVal;
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="GetTimeZoneOffset()">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="clientDateTime" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="offSet" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</body>
</html>
```

key point to notice here is,body has an attribute `onload`. Just give it a function name and that function will be called on page load.

---

Alternatively, you can also call the function on page load event like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = load();

function load() {
    var d = new Date()
    var gmtOffSet = -d.getTimezoneOffset();
    var gmtHours = Math.floor(gmtOffSet / 60);
    var GMTMin = Math.abs(gmtOffSet % 60);
    var dot = ".";
    var retVal = "" + gmtHours + dot + GMTMin;
    document.getElementById('<%= offSet.ClientID%>').value = retVal;
}

</script>
</head>
<body >
    <asp:HiddenField ID="clientDateTime" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="offSet" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Place this line before the closing script tag,writing from memory:

```
window.onload  = GetTimeZoneOffset;
```

i think the question is how to call the javascript function on pageload

Comment: Thanks for the edit @sachleen,I've posted the answer through my smart phone and there seems to be no code highlighting :-)

Comment: just add 4 spaces to the beginning of the line. :)

Answer (score 0):

use your code within

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function() {
        var d = new Date()
        var gmtOffSet = -d.getTimezoneOffset();
        var gmtHours = Math.floor(gmtOffSet / 60);
        var GMTMin = Math.abs(gmtOffSet % 60);
        var dot = ".";
        var retVal = "" + gmtHours + dot + GMTMin;
        document.getElementById('<%= offSet.ClientID%>').value = retVal;
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: This is incorrect syntax and throws exceptions. The correct implementation would be: window.onload = function() { };