# How to call javascript on user control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have webapplication in c# asp.net 4.0

I have User Control in that I have written javascript :-

```
<script>
    function SetValue() {        
        alert(document.getElementById('offSetClient').value);
    }
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="clientDateTime" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="offSetClient" runat="server" Value="Test"/>
```

and this User Control added into a web form.
Please suggest me how can I call this javascript on User Control page load.

Comment: You asked Same Question again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079029/how-to-call-javascript-function-on-page-load-in-asp-net/14079066#14079066

Comment: hey mona !! did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to attain this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ShowAlert", "SetValue('" + offSetClient.ClientID + "');", true);
}
```

Please add an input parameter for the function to get the object of hidden field and pass the same from function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SetValue(objHdn) {
    alert(document.getElementById(objHdn).value);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution but i already used this on user control's page load but it can not give message box with "Test"

Comment: am not getting you please explain.

Comment: Object of hidden field has to be passed to function instead of hard-coding the id directly. please check the edited answer.