# vb.net codebehind doesn't call javascript after using asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

.net question

i have a `asp:LinkButton`, when clicked it hits the code behind, creates a session and it calls a javascript function to open a new tab with PDF document

this is the button :

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="lnkBtn" ID="btnViewPDF" >
 <img alt="" src="External_Files/images/view_pdf_icon.png" />
  <span>View PDF</span></asp:LinkButton>
```

code behind :

```
      Protected Sub btnViewPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
       Handles btnViewPDF.Click

    Session("mina") = hfChartImg.Value
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "_viewPDF", 
       "changeUrl();",     True)
     End Sub
```

and this is the js function that opens the new tab with the pdf

```
  function changeUrl(){

      var url = 'CIP_frmCIPEventExplorePdf.aspx?ViewPDF=1&intCIPEventID=' + 
      $('#intCIPEventID').val();
       parent.showNewTab(url, 'CIP Chart - PDF', 'CIP');

     }
```

*this code worked fine till i had to use  to wrapp my page content* `asp:ScriptManager and asp:UpdatePanel`

here is what my code looks like now

```
  <body class="frame_content">
          <form id="CIP_frmCIPEventExplore" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"
              EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="dataview_title" >
          ..............................
            ..........................

       </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>  
       </form>

       </body>
```

**Question**
when i put a break point at the `session` line the code doesn't call the javascript function anymore, it hits the line and then the `END SUB` 
can any one tell me please where is my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem you have to use new method provided by scripmanger
So in you code instead of this

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
```

you have to use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock
```

Have a look at this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx

Comment: it did the trick but how can i pastback the original page , what it does now it generate the pdf page with the chart and then it keeps loading the other one , i think if i can do a refresh on this one this will help ,thanks

Comment: Sorry, i coudnt get your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. I encountered a similar problem where using `RegisterStartupScript()` would not work.  The following worked for me:

```
<form id="CIP_frmCIPEventExplore" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>   
           ...
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function (s, e) {
        changeUrl();
    });
</script>
```

See:
[Run javascript function after Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223837/run-javascript-function-after-postback)