# ASP.Net 2012 JQuery and Update Panel Not Working: One binded listbox and populating my results into another listbox using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox, asp.net-ajax

My listboxes are within the UpdatePanel.  I am using this code to transfer data from a binded listbox to an empty listbox to get my results.  I am using a dropdown to populate my results for the binded listbox.  What am I doing wrong here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#lstright").bind("click", function lstRight() {
            var options = $("[id*=lstListTenants1] option:selected");
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                $(options[i]).clone();
                $("[id*=lstListTenants2]").append(opt);
            }
        });

        $("#lstleft").bind("click", function lstLeft() {
            var options = $("[id*=lstListTenants2] option:selected");
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                $(options[i]).remove();
                //$("[id*=lstEmailAddress]").append(opt);
            }
        });
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); prm.add_endRequest(function (s, e) {
        $(function () {
            $("#lstright").bind("click", function lstRight() {
                var options = $("[id*=lstListTenants1] option:selected");
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                    $(options[i]).clone();
                    $("[id*=lstListTenants2]").append(opt);
                }
            });

            $("#lstleft").bind("click", function lstLeft() {
                var options = $("[id*=lstListTenants2] option:selected");
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                    $(options[i]).remove();
                    //$("[id*=lstEmailAddress]").append(opt);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I get jquery to work with my UpdatePanel so this will work properly?

Here is my aspx code:

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="h4" colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name and Address of Property Where Incident Occurred:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="h4">
                <asp:Label ID="lblPropName" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPropName" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPropName_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" Height="30px"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="h4">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="BU Number:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBUNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="h4">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Address1:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="h4">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Address2:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="h4">
                <asp:Label ID="lblListTenants" runat="server" Text="List of Affected Tenants:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:ListBox ID="lstListTenants1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="288px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="lstLeft" type="button" value="<<" />
                <input id="lstRight" type="button" value=">>" />
                <%--<asp:Button ID="btnLeft" runat="server" Text="<<" OnClick="btnLeft_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnRight" runat="server" Text=">>" OnClick="btnRight_Click" />--%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ListBox ID="lstListTenants2" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="288px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlPropName" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: WHAT is not working? what results do you get?

Comment: Nothing happens.  I try add my results to the other listbox with a simple button but nothing happens.  Nothing is brought over to the other listbox.

Answer (score 0):

For updatepannels, since they do partial postback, the jquery looses it's bind after partial postback. In this case you need to rebind the jquery function after postback.

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function (s, e) {
        // call your function here 
    });

Comment: How do I rebind the jquery function after postback?  I'm not sure how to do that. This is the issue that I am having.  I just do not know how to do it.

Comment: Still not sure where to put the var prm.  Where do I put that code?  I have tried just about everything and I think I may be just placing the code in the wrong place.  Can you tell me with my code above where to put this code so it knows to rebind after postback?

Comment: In the script block you have your main code. After your code add var prm and add your main code inside.

Comment: Can you show me with code?  Sorry, I am just really new to this.

Comment: <script type='javascript'>// your logic. var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function (s, e) {
       // your logic again 
    }); <script>

Comment: Are you using script manager? Add script manage. And try adding the script block after update panel

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223837/run-javascript-function-after-postback

Comment: I am using AjaxToolkit Script Manager.

Comment: Best way to debug javascript is to place alert after every line or use debugger; if using alert, faulty line will break the execution and the next alert Message won't appear.

Comment: Nothing seems to be working.  The only thing I can do is use the button_Click events but then I am having issues getting the results to post.