# Close image on modelpopup doesn't work after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have `ajax modelpopup extender` in my webform with `CancelControlID` set to an image `imgClose`. 
When I click on `imgClose` after popup has been displayed it closes the popup. But if I click on any controls or select some controls that require `postback`, clicking the image wouldn't do nothing at all.
Previously I had a button as `CancelControlID` for same `modelpopup`. It also had the same problem. I got around it with `OnClick="btnClose_Click"`codebehind method and hiding modelpopup.

For the `imgClose` I tried using client-side method but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Here's my `modelpopup extender` `image control` and `javascript`

```
<ajx:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnTest"
                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="divPreview" DropShadow="true"
                CancelControlID="imgClose">


    <div runat="server" id="divPreview">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="testDesign" runat="server" CssClass="boxdesignCustomerPopUp" Width="600px" Height="200px">
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <tr>                                            
                            <td>
                                <center>
                                    <strong>
                                        <asp:Literal ID="PopupTitleBar" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                    </strong>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; float: right; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;">                                                
                                <img id="imgClose" alt="Close" src="image/close-button-red.png" runat="server" onclick="closeModelPopup()" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="divMenu" style="float: left; width: 100px; height: auto">                                    
                </div>
                <div id="divBody" style="border: 2px">
                    <div id="divLedger" runat="server">
                        <hr />
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="designtextfont">Has Ledger</td>
                                    <td class="designtextbox">
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoLedgerYes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="hasLedgerRdo"
                                                    Text="Yes" OnCheckedChanged="rdoLedgerYes_CheckedChanged" />
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoLedgerNo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="hasLedgerRdo"
                                                    Text="No" OnCheckedChanged="rdoLedgerNo_CheckedChanged" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeModelPopUp() {
        $find('ModalPopupExtender1').hide();           
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `imgClose` button into the `divPreview` outside of `UpdatePanel`. Also you shouldn't need the `onclick` in the `imgClose` because the `ModalPopupExtender` handles it by setting the `CancelControlID` property.

Comment: I do actually have imgClose in divPreview. I have updated the post... so you can refer to it... Reason I had to put onclick was that imgClose doesnt work after there is a postback. divMenu and divBody contains several controls that trigger various postback functions.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add a button that makes the imgClose stop working please? I tried myself and it is working here but when I open my modal, i cannot do any postback because there is a overlay div blocking the whole page except the modal.

Comment: Sorry, I tried something different: moved your imgClose to outside of UpdatePanel but inside divPreview.

Comment: I have updated my code in the post... I have added some controls I've been using that trigger a postback...

Comment: Hi buddy. Try this example...
Default.aspx.cs: [http://pastebin.com/kdNx7icb](http://pastebin.com/kdNx7icb). After the postback, the close button loses its click handler. If you want to use your custom click handler and bind it after every postback you can do something like in this post [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4223963/3000462](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4223963/3000462).

Comment: I just visited pastebin for the example. Yep it does work. Just had to position my imgClose just outside of UpdatePanel but inside of divPreview. I misunderstood your earlier comment.. and thought it didn't work. Thanks