# Need to trigger Javascript code when doing a SharePoint List search

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm looking for function code to trigger javascript code upon performing a search on SharePoint list

I have a SharePoint list that i have edited and added a script editor code snippet shown here to force hyperlinks in the list to open in a new tab by adding the #openinnewwindow to the end of the links. This code works great on the list when it loads. However if i perform a search the search result links do not open in a new tab. I believe if i re-trigger the code again this would allow the links to open in new tabs just not sure what to add to trigger.

`    
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("rewriteLinks");

```
 function rewriteLinks() {
  //create an array to store all
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

  //loop through the array
  for (var x=0; x<anchors.length; x++) {
    //check to see if the current anchor element contain  
#openinnewwindow 
    if (anchors[x].outerHTML.indexOf('#openinnewwindow')>0) {
      //add the [target] attribute and rewrite the [href] attribute
      anchors[x].target = "_blank";
      anchors[x].href = anchors[x].href.replace(/#openinnewwindow/,'');
    }
  }
}
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be looking for is to have your function run after each postback.  Check out solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223837/run-javascript-function-after-postback) on Stackoverflow.  I'm copying the relevant bits from that accepted answer:

You can use the ClientScriptManager to make a call to a function on the reload:
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AKey", "MyFunction();", true);

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx